# Запись в ступенчатом порядке csv Python

Tags: python, csv

Я произвожу парсер сайта. Мне нужно записать данные в csv файл в ступенчатом порядке (фото с примером ниже), но у меня происходит запись все в одну строчку. Подскажите, как можно решить данную проблему?

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv


class Tesco:
    def get_html(self, url):
        r = requests.get(url)
        return r.text

    def write_csv(self, data):
        with open('tesco.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)

        writer.writerow((
            data['category'],
            data['sub_category_1'],
            data['sub_category_2'],
            data['sub_category_3'],
        ))

    def get_page_data(self, html):
        main_soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

        groceries = main_soup.find('ul', class_='menu-superdepartment').find_all('li')[:-1]
        for grocery in groceries:
            category = (re.sub(r'Shop|department', '', grocery.find('span').text)).lower()

            category_url = 'https://www.tesco.com' + grocery.find('a').get('href')
            category_html = self.get_html(category_url)
            category_soup = BeautifulSoup(category_html, 'lxml')
            sub_groceries = category_soup.find('div', class_='current').find_all('li')[1:]
            for sub_grocery in sub_groceries:
                sub_category_1 = (re.sub(r"'", "", sub_grocery.find('span', class_='list-item-single-line').text)).lower()

                sub_category_1_url = 'https://www.tesco.com' + sub_grocery.find('a').get('href')
                sub_category_1_html = self.get_html(sub_category_1_url)
                sub_category_1_soup = BeautifulSoup(sub_category_1_html, 'lxml')
                sub_groceries_1 = sub_category_1_soup.find('div', class_='current').find_all('li')[1:]
                for sub_grocery_1 in sub_groceries_1:
                    sub_category_2 = (re.sub(r"'", "", sub_grocery_1.find('span', class_='list-item-single-line').text)).lower()


                    sub_category_2_url = 'https://www.tesco.com' + sub_grocery_1.find('a').get('href')
                    sub_category_2_html = self.get_html(sub_category_2_url)
                    sub_category_2_soup = BeautifulSoup(sub_category_2_html, 'lxml')

                    try:
                        check = sub_category_2_soup.find('div', class_='empty-section').find('span', class_='icon-info2')
                    except:
                        check = ''

                    if check == '':
                        sub_groceries_2 = sub_category_2_soup.find('div', class_='filter-options')\
                            .find_all('li', class_='filter-option__container')
                        for sub_grocery_2 in sub_groceries_2:
                            sub_category_3 = sub_grocery_2.find('label', class_='checkbox-label').get('title').lower()

                            data = {
                                'category': category,
                                'sub_category_1': sub_category_1,
                                'sub_category_2': sub_category_2,
                                'sub_category_3': sub_category_3,
                            }

                            self.write_csv(data)


def main():
    tesco = Tesco()

    url = 'https://www.tesco.com/groceries/en-GB'
    tesco.get_page_data(tesco.get_html(url))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Нужно, чтобы было вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А записывается вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: модуль `csv` предназначен для работы с CSV файлами. То что вы пытаетесь сделать - не является CSV файлом - прочитать (распарсить) его как CSV будет __очень__ сложно.

Comment: Я парсю сайт и записываю данные в csv, почему это сложно?

Comment: Попробуйте создать ручками "ступенчатый" CSV и распарсить его...

Comment: стоит различать: как данные храняться (у вас уже правильно). От того как они отображаются: можно задать вопрос: есть такой-то cvs файл (привести несколько строк в виде *текста*, а не картинки), как его отобразить не повторяя подряд идущих значений в столбце¶ Если вы хотите и хранить без повторения, то это можно сделать, но неудобно работать будет.

Comment: второй скрин - отличный csv, делать его "ступенчатым" создаст многопроблем в дальнейшем